# axios.post response got data, but response.data is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

**UPDATED**

It is expected for the API to returned as in XML Format. After using console.log I can see and retrieve the response.data in XML structure.
But when xml2json conversion, it returned me empty object.

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
};

const response = await axios.post(postURL, urlSearchParams, { timeout: constant.axiosTimeout, headers: headers });

// logger.custom.info('responseXML:: ', response); //Show list of things
// logger.custom.info('responseXML_DATA:: ', response.data); //Empty

console.log('responseXML:: ', response.data); //SUCCESS

const options = {
    compact: true,
    trim: true,
    ignoreDeclaration: true,
    ignoreInstruction: true,
    ignoreAttributes: true,
    ignoreComment: true,
    ignoreCdata: true,
    ignoreDoctype: true,
    textFn: utils.xml2jsonRemoveJsonTextAttribute
  };

// JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(response.data, options));

console.log('xml2json:: ', convert.xml2json(response.data, options));
console.log('JSONParse:: ', JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(response.data, options)));
```

[image]
[image]

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: and what does `console.log(response.data)` say? i.e. maybe it's the logger..

Comment: @traynor same, it show empty.

Comment: what does `console.log(response.headers)` say? also, the object doesn't look like [axios response](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema)..

Comment: I see an empty `result` element with a `msg` attribute that says "Key error."  Is it possible your query needs to provide a key to access the expected data?

Comment: @traynor Sorry, my mistake. Just now I I did tried again with console.log with response.data it does return me the expected value. But any idea why during xml2json conversion it return empty object? I will update the post again.

Comment: @phatfingers, It doesn't matter what's the response message right. By right my application should capture and convert and corresponding response and show in front-end.

Comment: @JackWong Try changing your `ignoreAttributes` option to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue of the logging by using console.log instead of logger.
On regards of the xml2json parsing issue is due to the ignoreAttributes I set to TRUE.

After try and error, I noticed that Attributes is referring to this tag
[image]

And since my response from the API is

```
<?xml version"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result info="xxxx" msg="yyyy" />
```

So during xml2json conversion it will ignore the tag and return empty.

Hope this clarify.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `await`.

*Try this:*

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
};

const response = await axios.post(postURL, urlSearchParams, { timeout: constant.axiosTimeout, headers: headers });

console.log('responseXML:: ', await response); //Show list of things
console.log('responseXML_DATA:: ', await response.data); //Empty
```

Comment: Hi, result still got the same.

Comment: I have edited now with `console.log`. With this I got the result in logs

Comment: Hi, console.log return me the result. But why during xml2json return empty json object? I will edit and update the post again